# How can I define a "global" job variable that each processor can read/update using Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch job with a reader/processor/writer that reads a batch of EmailQueue records, processes/sends them, and then writes the results (success, fail) back into the EmailQueue database table. However, if during the job I have 5+ emails that fail to send (e.g. because the email API is down), I would like the processor to not attempt the send, but instead, mark the remaining EmailQueue objects as "failed" - and then store back in to the database with the writer. I would like my processor look something like the one below, but I can't figure out how to have a "global" monitor for the job that the processor can access.

It may be important to note that my `appUserEmailSender.send(emailQueue)` method doesn't throw an error if the email failed to send, it only stores the results in the EmailQueue object itself so I can write the results back into the EmailQueue db table.

```
public EmailQueue process(@NonNull EmailQueue emailQueue) {

    // can this variable be defined globally for each job somewhere???
    int emailFailSendCount = 0;

    // if fail count less than 5, attempt to send email
    if (emailFailSendCount<5) {

        // send the email
        EmailQueue result = appUserEmailSender.send(emailQueue);
       
        // If failed, increase fail count
        if (EmailQueueState.FAILED == result.getEmailQueueState()) {
            emailFailSendCount++;
        }

    // if fail count > 5, don't attempt to send, just mark as "failed"
    } else {
        emailQueue.setEmailQueueState(EmailQueueState.FAILED);
    }

    return emailQueue;
}
```

Clearly the above code wouldn't work, but my question is can I define a "global" `emailFailSendCount` variable that each process can read or update on each processing step?

Comment: Make your processor a `JobListener` or `StepListener` and store the value in the job or step context. You can simply add a method that takes a `StepExecution` and annotate the method with `@BeforeStep`. Store the `StepExecution` as an instance variable do `getExecutionContext` and you can store/get variables for the duration of the step. The same applies to an `@BeforeJob` with a `JobExecution`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Let me look into all these concepts and circle back.

Comment: Are you saying that my `EmailQueueBatchProcessor` should implement both `ItemProcessor` and `ItemProcessListener`?  Also, I having trouble figuring out how exactly I should implement your suggestion.  Any chance you can post an answer with a quick "template"? (doesn't have to be complete obviously)

Comment: How does a `JobLIstener` translate to an `ItemProcessListener`? There is an actual interface called `JobListener` and one called `StepListener`. Or you can just use the mentioned annotations (for which you can quite easily lookup the documentation).

Comment: The reason I "translated" to `ItemProcessListiner` is because I needed the listener to run before and after the "process" step.  The JobListener and StepListener classes only execute before and after the job or (all) steps.  Anyway, I eventually discovered that I could just insert a variable inside my process bean and track it that way - because the process bean has StepScope, the variable will stay valid throughout the step and then obviously reset on the next job run.